# Sign-Up or Sign-In policy error in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I’m trying to create a single Sign-Up or Sign-In policy but I get the following error message:
There was an error while creating the policy ‘An object was not found while retrieving extension properties in tenant “73a55309-…”. Error returned was 404/Request_ResourceNotFound: Resource ‘7c7ab660-…’ does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.’

Despite this error my policy has been created but I think it’s not working correctly because I’m trying to sign up on the default page and after this action I see blank page with ‘Bad Request’.

EDIT 1: I made all the steps on the basis of https://cgillum.tech/2016/05/27/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c/

EDIT 2: On the MSDN forum they suggest I delete my 'b2c-extensions-app' but I don't know what it is and where I can find it. I've checked it in Azure classic portal -> Active Directory -> My AAD B2C -> Applications my company owns: there is only my 'test' application.

**SOLUTION:** They are right on the MSDN forum. I've created a new AAD B2C and 'b2c-extensions-app' has been created automatically. After that I have no problems with creation of policy.

Comment: how are you trying to create the policy, what steps are you taking/ what instructions are you following? The more information you add about potential causes the easier it become for other to help you

Comment: I've edited my question and have added the link to tutorial that I used.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already indicated, if you are seeing the error

> "An object was not found while retrieving extension properties in tenant "

while performing any operation in Azure AD B2C, that indicates that the b2c-extensions app has been deleted.

It might be possible for you to restore the applications by leveraging Azure AD Graph's /deletedApplications endpoint. See this other post for more info: [How to add b2c-extensions-app in Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526183/how-to-add-b2c-extensions-app-in-azure-ad-b2c)

Alternatively, as per your approach, you can create a brand new Azure AD B2C tenant which will have this application and just be careful not to delete the b2c-extensions application again.