# How to add b2c-extensions-app in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created a few B2C directories using the classic Azure portal.  Sometimes it adds the b2c-extensions-app but other times it does not.  When I delete a directory, Azure seems to have a long memory which prevents me from trying to recreate it (with the same name).

Is there a way to manually add the b2c-extensions-app such that it shows up under "Applications my Company Owns" listing?

Comment: Try using the Graph API to query the b2c-extension-app and list the changes between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The b2c-extensions-app is created automatically as part of creating an Azure AD B2C tenant. It should **always** be created. If you create a new tenant and this app is not present, you should open a support case so that the Azure AD B2C team can look into this.

> **Important note**: The b2c-extensions-app is **only** visible in the App Registrations blade and not via the B2C Settings > Applications blade. See screenshots at the bottom.

More likely, someone accidentally deleted the application. If that's the case, there's two options:

1. If the application was deleted less than 30 days ago, you can use the Azure AD Graph's [/deletedApplications/{application_id}/restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/functions-and-actions#restore) api to bring it back.
2. If it's been more than 30 days, there's no way to restore the application and you'll have to reach out to Azure support to get help on recreating and rewiring the application to your B2C tenant.

---

Notice that it's available in App registrations:

**NOTE:** Make sure you pick "All apps" from the App Registration drop-down.

[image: Find app registrations]
[image: Entry present in app registrations]

But not in the B2C Applications:

[image: Entry not visible in b2c apps]

Comment: I definitely didn't delete it so I guess I'll open a support ticket.  I haven't tested it but I wonder if only the first one gets the app and all subsequent ones do not.

Comment: Note for anyone that finds this in the future: The app registration blades is default to "My apps" as of today.  Make sure to switch to "All apps" to find it.